Why do some AppImage apps not integrate properly into dash to dock?
I am on ubuntu 24.04 running gnome & dash to dock as a dock, and I have all my important apps in the dock.
Usually, when I launch a new app, I will have a right-click menu in dash, which allows me to pin the app to the dock. Not so however with some AppImage apps, but not all. And I have no clue what it is about.
For example:

Ledger Live (app for ledger hardware crypto wallet) can be pinned to the dock and shows a proper icon
Firefly (IOTA wallet) can be pinned to the dock but does not show a proper icon
FreeCAD / BambuStudio can not be pinned to the dock and does not show a proper icon.

All 4 AppImages have been "integrated" after the prompt in the same way, so they have been moved to $HOME/Applications and a .desktop file has been created in $HOME/.local/share/applications.
Why can I not integrate 2) and 3) properly? When I use the regular gnome launcher (e.g. press Windows key) to search for the app, it will be shown with the correct icon (all 4 above apps), and I can open any of them without issues.
So this might be a dash to dock issue, since regular launcher works? How can I fix this?

AppImage are self-contained and portable app distribution packages. How it behaves in Gnome, KDE, or any other Desktop Environment (DE) depends on the creator of the AppImage package. This is my guess.

Not omy app but I strongly recommend you use AppImageLauncher [here]https://github.com/TheAssassin/AppImageLauncher/releases/tag/continuous) and download the bionic .deb file for your hardware and ninstall it in your enviroment, and launch it.  It'll catch your execution of AppImages and copy them to where they should be and create .desktop files for integration

@mook765 yeah it was a typo
